# The Puzzle on the graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, matrix, network-flow

Given an undirected graph G=(V,E), each node i is associated with 'Ci' number of objects. At each step, for every node i, the Ci objects are divided up equally among i's neighbors. After K steps, output the number of objects of the top five nodes which has the most objects.

Here is one example of what happens in one step:
[image]
Objects of A is divided equally by B and C.
 
Objects of B is divided equally by A and C.
 
Objects of C is divided equally by A and B.

Some Constrains:
|V|<10^5,  |E|<2*10^5,  K<10^7,  Ci<1000

My current idea is: represent the transformation in each step with a matrix.
This problem is converted to the calculation of the power of matrix. But this solution is much too slow considering |V| can be 10^5.

> Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: Comment have you heard of PageRank? That seems similar to what you want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank it'd need some modifications though...

Comment: Can a single object be associated with multiple nodes?  When you say “the Ci objects will be taken away by the neighbors of i equally”, do you mean that each neighbor of i becomes associated with all of the objects that were associated with i?  Or are the objects associated with i somehow divided up amongst i's neighbors?

Comment: |V| is 10^5 but the matrix doesn't have to take |V|*|V|, if you are using an adjacency matrix, the matrix will be very sparse, with |E| nonzero cells at most, so you might not have a problem if you use a sparse representation. You know you need to diagonalize the matrix right?

Comment: What is the source of this problem ?

Comment: @rob mayoff The objects are divided up equally amongst i's neighbors

Answer (score 1):

The matrix equation for a single step is like `M x = x'`, where `x` is a vector of current node contents, and `x'` is the contents after one step.  That is, `x' = M x`.  The contents at the step after that is `x" = M x' = M(M x)`.  An example of M follows, where the graph's adjacency matrix is shown at left.  The column headed `#nbr` is the number of neighbors of nodes a, b ... e.  Matrix `M` is formed from the adjacency matrix by replacing each 1 with a fraction equal to the number of ones in the same column.

```
  a b c d e  #nbr          matrix M
a 0 0 1 1 0   2       0   0  1/3 1/4  0
b 0 0 0 1 0   1       0   0   0  1/4  0
c 1 0 0 1 1   3      1/2  0   0  1/4 1/2
d 1 1 1 0 1   4      1/2  1  1/3  0  1/2
e 0 0 1 1 0   2       0   0  1/3 1/4  0
```

To do K steps starting with initial contents `x`, just compute `(M^K) x`.  Use an [exponentiation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Efficient_computation_of_integer_powers) that requires `lg K` matrix multiplications, `lg` representing logarithms to base 2.  As matrix multiplication typically is of O(n^3) complexity, this method is O(lg K * n^3) if straightforwardly implemented, or O(lg K * n^2.376) if using Coppersmith/Winograd algorithm.  The complexity can be reduced to O(n^2.376)  – that is, we can drop the `lg K` multiplier –  by [diagonalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) M into form (P^-1)AP, from which `M^K = (P^-1)(A^K)P`, and `A^K` is an O(n lg K) operation, giving O(n^2.376) overall. Diagonalization typically costs O(n^3), but is O(n^2.376) [using Coppersmith/Winograd algorithm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62904/complexity-of-eigenvalue-decomposition).

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. I forget about those things about diagonalizing. Your idea do make it faster. Another problem is: will diagonalization be faster if the matrix is sparse?

Comment: Some of the iterative methods for eigenvalues are faster for sparse matrices, and if you can organize your matrix into blocks, eigen problems can be solved for the blocks, with significant time savings.  Beyond that I don't remember much